# Como pegar o valor de uma linha selecionada de uma table html

Tags: javascript, html, table

Gostaria que ao clicar em uma linha da table me retornasse o valor da coluna selecionada apenas . Meu codigo traz todos os valores das tags td porem como a table sera montada dinamicamente preciso que ela me exiba apenas o valor da linha selecionada. 
 `function selLinha(linha, multiplos) {
                var dados = "";
                dados += "ID: " + document.getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML;
                alert(dados);
            }`

Note que para pegar o valor é preciso passar a posicao dele na tag `etElementsByTagName("td")[3]`. html table `<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>IP</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="  cursor: pointer;" onclick="ts()">
                    <td style="  cursor: pointer;">12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="  cursor: pointer;" onclick="ts()">
                    <td style="  cursor: pointer;">22</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </thead>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se é que eu entendi vc precisa fazer um `forEach` para pegar cada `td` clicada, depois vc usa um `e.currentTarget.id` pra pegar apenas o `id` do elemento clicado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```js
var td = document.querySelectorAll('td');

td.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', meuID);
});

function meuID(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
}
```

```html
<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>IP</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="  cursor: pointer;">
            <td style="  cursor: pointer;" id="n1">12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="  cursor: pointer;">
            <td style="  cursor: pointer;" id="n2">22</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Perdoe a ignorancia , mas por que você não usou a "onclick"?

Comment: @MatheusIsac não vou falar que `onclick` se uma ma prática, mas é desnecessário na maioria dos casos. Até pq se vc tiver 100 elementos e quiser mudar por exemplo de onclick para mouseOver, ou mudar o nome da função, vc tiver que mudar o código nos 100 elementos. Além de repetir código atoa já que da forma como eu fiz te pouparia alguns KBs dependendo do tamanho da tabela. Para finalizar ele não é muito bom para dar manutenção no sistema, pois fica difícil saber qual seletor está chamando a função, vc vai ter que procurar no código quem tem o onclick, com o seletor definido vc já vê isso direto